# Is there a way to create intenet in Dialogflow for the Contact type in Telegram

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram, telegram-bot

I am making a Telegram bot using Dialogflow and I want to know if there is a way to make Dialogflow respond to when a user shares his contact?

In Telegram users can send messages as well as share their contact or location information as explained here. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#contact

Currently there is no native event available in Dialogflow to for Telegram contact or location type. There is a system event however for Facebook location sharing.

Is there a way to create a custom event for Telegram contact? Or any other way to make Dialogflow respond to when a user sends a his contact?

Thanks

Comment: if you are not using one-click integration, You will recive data in your webhook when user shares his contact

Comment: Yes that's the only way I can see for now. But I was interested in learning if it is doable with one-click integration. Thanks anyway!